# How to recreate this iOS application view and animations?

Tags: ios, animation, uikit

I am new to iOS development and unable to identify how Google/YouTube built this view in the YouTubeTV app. Is this built using an UITableView?
Essentially, the top row is selectable ([Pre-animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKcBn.jpg)). As you scroll up, the top row gets pushed up and out of view ([Mid-animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7WBu.jpg)), while the second row fades and grows into, and replaces, the top row). I've included screenshots of the animation in-progress. Thanks for the info and assistance.

Comment: have you tried this show us the code

Comment: I have not tried this yet. I was trying to identify the right UIKit objects to use before attempting.

Answer (score 0):

This would be done with a `UITableView` or a `UICollectionView`. What you would do is enable paging on the Table/Collection view, so that it only ever displays entire cells in the visible area of the view. You can then manipulate the height use the `heightForCellAtIndexPath:` function - as an example of how it could be done on a tableview.

There is actually a really good example on github - typically we try to give more full answers on SO, but in this case, this could be relevant to you just starting out. Not affiliated in anyway, but it's a really good example.

https://github.com/aslanyanhaik/youtube-iOS